# How to Fetch username only from the result set

Tags: iphone, ios, addressbook, ios5

How to get the username value only from the addressbook, when selecting a twitter detail of contact

```
if ( property == kABPersonSocialProfileProperty) {

        ABMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property);


        for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(multi); i++) {

            CFStringRef socialLabel = ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(multi, identifier));

            CFStringRef social = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, i);

            NSDictionary* personaddress =(NSDictionary*) ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, i);        

            NSString*twitterdetails = [personaddress valueForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonSocialProfileServiceTwitter];
            NSLog(@"%@ twitterdetails",twitterdetails);  


            NSString *aString = (NSString *)social;


            NSLog(@"%@ aString",aString);
        }
```

I am getting the result as below

```
{
    service = twitter;
    url = "http://twitter.com/manoas2136";
    username = manoas2136;
} aString
```

please tell me how to get only the username from the above result set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try  this code

```
  NSDictionary* personalDetails = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, i)];
  NSString* aString = [personalDetails valueForKey:@"username"];
  NSLog(@"%@ aString",aString);
```

result manoas2136 aString

you converted the NSDictionary value in to string so it clubbed all result of NSDictionary to NSString so you extract only username by using valueForKey:

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this way to fetch the twitter address from the iphone contactlist. and it works fine..

```
ABMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonSocialProfileProperty);

for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(multi); i++) 
{

    NSDictionary* personalDetails = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, i)];
    NSLog(@"%@",personalDetails);

    NSString* aString1 = [personalDetails valueForKey:@"username"];
    NSLog(@"%@ aString",aString1);
    Twitter.text = [personalDetails valueForKey:@"username"];
}
//get Twitter Address end....
```